# Thunderbird only loads "inbox"? How about the other folders that already exists?

Tags: thunderbird

I am wondering why Thunderbird only loads my inbox and ignores the rest of the folders I have created using my internet browser?

Thanks.

Comment: You're talking about folders you made in some webmail application like gmail?

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh Yeah, but I've just sorted it out....there is a plug-ing option in Thunderbird for those extra folder. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to select and right click on the folder and select `Properties`

[image: Thunderbird Folder Properties]

and then Check the option `When getting new messages for this account, always check this folder`

[image: Check this folder when checking new mails]